# how to pre-populate form with ngModel binding

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have created a `Modal` page where i want to show `pre-populated` `data` to user whenever user `edits` `data` it must bind to my local `collectDataInModalPage_afterEdit`.

**demo Here**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-jse3zv?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

**problem:**  `[(ngModel)]="collectDataInModalPage_afterEdit"` <= this `ngModel` is leaving `form` blank because it is set to blank in the `begining` here it is

```
    collectDataInModalPage_afterEdit = {
       "first_name":"",
       "last_name":"",
      "mobile_number":""
  };
```

**i took out `[(ngModel)]` for `mobile_number` field  which is populated, see demo**

**Question :** i want to `pre-populate` the form with this `data` => `userDataBeforeEdit` and want to collect `data` to this =>`collectDataInModalPage_afterEdit`

**demo here**:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-jse3zv?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  userDataBeforeEdit = {
    "first_name":"John",
  "last_name":"Doe",
  "mobile_number":"98869934445",
};

collectDataInModalPage_afterEdit = {    "first_name":"","last_name":"","mobile_number":""};      

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>         
    <ion-input type="text" value="{{userDataBeforeEdit.first_name}}" [(ngModel)]="collectDataInModalPage_afterEdit.first_name"></ion-input>                
 </ion-item> 


 <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Last Name</ion-label>   
    <ion-input type="text" value="userDetails" [(ngModel)]="collectDataInModalPage_afterEdit.last_name"></ion-input>                
  </ion-item> 


   <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Phone Number</ion-label>   
    <ion-input type="text" value="{{userDataBeforeEdit.mobile_number}}"></ion-input>                         
  </ion-item>
```

Please Help me thanks in Adavance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do in this case is to just use `Object.assign` and skip the `value` altogether, so:

```ts
collectDataInModalPage_afterEdit = {};     

ngOnInit() {
  this.collectDataInModalPage_afterEdit = Object.assign({},this.userDataBeforeEdit)
}
```

Then you can just use `this.collectDataInModalPage_afterEdit` in your template with `[(ngModel)]`

DEMO: https://ionic-ovntia.stackblitz.io

I don't see how it would be possible to use `value` and `ngModel` in this case like you are trying to.

Other option would be, if this is a form (seems like it could be) is to build the form (with `value`) as such, that upon submit you can assign the form object directly to your variable `collectDataInModalPage_afterEdit`